# How do I pass an ArrayList<String> from one method to another in Java. Variable not initialised error

Tags: java, string, random, arraylist, pass-by-reference

New to Java coding, please bear with me.
I'm trying to pass my ArrayList chosenWords held in my method getChosenWords(int length) to my method getRandom(int length). I need the ArrayList so I can chose a random index and return a random string.

Note, it's not declared in the Class fields and **I am not able to change the parameters of my methods**. I have to find another way to pass the `ArrayList` in but I'm unsure how to. The unit test uses these set parameters and I can't change parameters or the fields as other classes rely on them staying the same.

I'm pretty sure this is the line that needs changing `ArrayList<String> chosenWords;`
and currently I have an error *variable not initialised* on this line. `random.nextInt(chosenWords.size());`

Any suggestions?

**Method1**

```
// Takes strings in ArrayList words and stores strings with char int length to ArrayList chosenWords

public ArrayList<String> getChosenWords(int length) {
       ArrayList<String> chosenWords = new ArrayList<>(); 
       
       for(String word1 : words) {
            if(word1.length() == length) {
                 chosenWords.add(word1);
            }
       }
       return chosenWords;  
}
```

**Method2**

```
//Returns a randomly selected string from ArrayList chosenWords

public String getRandom(int length) {
    ArrayList<String> chosenWords;
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomIndex = random.nextInt(chosenWords.size());
    return chosenWords.get(randomIndex);        
}
```

Comment: Your method `getChosenWords` returns the locale arraylist you create. Use that and call that method to get the List: `ArrayList<String> chosenWords = getChosenWords(length);`

Comment: Why does `getRandom` take an `int` parameter? You don't use it anywhere. Are you sure you have the method parameters correct for both of your methods?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I tried that but kept putting in (int length) at the end, I didn't realise I don't put the type in.  Thank you. Very grateful.

Comment: Please add the unit test to your question.

Comment: @matt the int parameter is being used in my solution provided here.
I can't change the parameters because the unit test relies on it.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution, if the OP hasn't used it yet?

```
public String getRandom(int length) {
    ArrayList<String> chosenWords = getChosenWords(length);
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomIndex = random.nextInt(chosenWords.size());
    return chosenWords.get(randomIndex);        
}
```

That way chosenWords will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of receiving `length` as a parameter in the `getRandom()` function, take an ArrayList. Pass the arraylist `chosenWords` to the `getRandom()` function and return the value received from the `getRandom()` function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: All of that would make sense if the asker hasn't specified " I am not able to change the parameters of my methods."